# Reducing delay of appearance of circle in secure UITextField

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, security, uitextfield

I have a UITextField where I want to type a password and also, I have set UITextField secure property in IB. Now, my question is that When I am typing the password, it shows the characters for some duration and then shows the black circles, how can I reduce this delay?

Comment: I think this is standard .... but plz post ur code for viewing :)

Comment: @Gill he made only UITextField as secure. there is no any other code used for the same.

Comment: UITextField *txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 130, 100, 20)];
txtPassword.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    txtPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;
    txtPassword.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:txtPassword];
    [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: @RahulGupta now u say that wen u type the password for example it is revealed and then after some time it converts it to a dot rite ? u want it simultaneously ? Pls check in the device coz in simulator it might be slow...

Comment: @Gill Thanks mere bai. I don't want to show the password, characters should get directly converted to dot. I am checking on Device not the simulator. It stays for around 2 seconds.

Comment: @RahulGupta yr i think thats probable

Comment: @Gill ya you are right...we can do some customization there, but I don't know..apple will allow it or not..because this is default behavior of Apple.

Comment: @SunilTarge exactly, and I think this has been done to give the user 2-3 sec time interval to see wat he has typed otherwise theres always the chance of a confusion and then one has to retype the password all over again ....